# Stop concordance printing 'no matches' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I'm applying a concordance command over each item in a list. It works fine, but when it does not find a match, it prints out `No matches`. I would like it to ignore those and only print out results for matches.

`absol` is the variable that contains the list

Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
def get_all_phrases_containing_tar_wrd(target_word, tar_passage, left_margin = 10, right_margin = 10):
    Ellis = nltk.word_tokenize(tar_passage)
    text = nltk.Text(Ellis)
    c = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(text.Ellis, key = lambda s: s.lower())
    concordance_txt = ([text.Ellis[map(lambda x: x-5 if (x-left_margin)&gt[0] else 0, [offset])[0]:offset+right_margin]
                    for offset in c.offsets(target_word)])
    return [''.join([x+' ' for x in con_sub]) for con_sub in concordance_txt]

Ellis = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
text = nltk.Text(Ellis)
for t_word in absol:
    text.concordance(t_word)
print
print 'Results from function'
results = get_all_phrases_containing_tar_wrd(absol, raw)
for result in results:
    print result
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: yes, I'm not sure how to get this script to ignore the items which it cannot match..and only print out the matches.  The list is very long...almost 200 items and only a few items are actually matched...this means I get a very long list of 'no matches'.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I get this script to ignore the items it cannot match and not print out 'No match' as it currently does.  I'm sorry I don't know enough about python to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, you have these lines:

```
text = nltk.Text(Ellis)
for t_word in absol:
    text.concordance(t_word)
```

You can replace those lines with these:

```
ci = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(Ellis)
for t_word in absol:
    if ci.offsets(t_word):
        ci.print_concordance(t_word)
```

The extra `if` will cause the script to ignore the items it cannot match. Note that you have to switch from using the `Text` object to the more specific `ConcordanceIndex` object.